# I want to change only folder icons from humanity theme.How do i do it?

Tags: themes, icons, faenza, icon-themes

I love the new Files, app center and software update icons specially an thus want to remain on humanity icon set.

But i hate the folders!

i want to use the folders from the Faenza icon set. Which folder should i copy from the faenza icon set to the humanity icon set so that this happens?

Thankyou! :)

Comment: which size should i choose? there is 'scalable' in faenza....but not in humanity! and vice versa for 128! i mean ill copy all folders but then i hope 128 is not the one used by default! coz the scalable ones are also at 96px max in faenza

Comment: okay tell me how can i use only the indicator icons form another theme? ( i want to use them from faenza again)(so my final set up should be - humanity icons for apps.Faenza icons for folders and inidators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the folder icons in Humanity for those of Faenza you have to copy/paste the Faenza folders `Faenza/places/[size]` in `Humanity/places/[size]`.

The sizes are set in the `index.theme` file. You can copy/paste the folders and edit the file to use the sizes you want/have.

From the comments:

If you want to change the indicator icons too copy the `status` folder.

Comment: okay just incase i want to do the opposite? i want to edit the faenza theme to keep evrerything else same, but have all app icons to be from humanity? i ask this coz faenza already has lots f icons in it, but humanity doesnt have pre-kept icons...?

Comment: Just replace the folders you want to use. If you want the app icons from Humanity copy/paste the app folder into Faenza and edit the `ìndex.theme` file accordingly.

Comment: but as i said, humanity does not have a pre-saved set of icons like faenza.. for eg, apps folder in default faenza icon theme will have a chrome icon already present in it! but the apps icon from humanity doesnt have nything like this! from where does the humanity theme get those icons?

Comment: From the `hicolor` folder in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/apps[size]`.

Comment: okay so is there any way i can directly ask the faenza icon set to collect icons from there? if i have to edit the index file then plz guide me what to edit! m a noob at themes editing n stuff! untill now ive just installed them n used.. :P

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the Faenza theme except for the app icons which you want to replace with Humanity's is this correct?.

Comment: Yup! Faenza Icon Set Should be the theme in use, but the app icons should be from humanity theme.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9136/discussion-between-uri-herrera-and-nirmik)